# Merging the content of one website to other

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, migration

I had two websites. 6 months ago my second website expired and now I want to merge the blog content of second website into first website.

Will it give any negative impact on SEO of first website? What must be taken care of in this process?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how strong is your first website. If it's strong then you should not observe negative impact. To be save I recommend you to redirect (301) each page of your second website to the new URL.

Comment: Yes my first website is stronger than the second website. Is there a way to let know that i am merging two sites.? So google would better understand.

Comment: Yes, there is a way: you just need to redirect your content using 301 redirect from your second website to your fist website (you would need to recover the domain if it expired).

Comment: Ohhh but sadly i am not able to recover it :(